# Best algorithm for inversion of symmetric positive-definite matrices

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, matrices

As I know, the time complexity for usual inversion algorithm of general matrix is $O(n^3)$. In recent years, there is a improvement from $O(n^3)$ to $O(n^{2.8....})$. However, does there exists a faster inversion algorithm for **symmetric positive-definite matrices**? I have tried to search the answer but the best answer I have seen is to inverse the symmetric positive-definite matrix by using Cholesky decomposition. However, its complexity is also $O(n^3)$.

Could you provide me the fastest algorithm (even only the name) for inversion of symmetric positive-definite matrices?

Comment: I think you mean $O(n^{2.38...}）$. inversion of general matrix takes the same amount of time as matrix multiplication.

Comment: Have you looked in the Knuth book for references?